# server doesn't respond on POST Request with CURL + PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, curl

I have a simple PHP Script, that uses CURL to send a HTTP Post Request to a remote server.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://91.250.77.10/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('a' => 'b'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($error) 
    echo $error;
else
    echo $contents;
```

This results in an error: "no response from server". The request can't be found in the access log of the remote server, too!

What's more, if I send the postfields as a querystring, i.e.:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '&a=b');
```

then everything is just fine.

It seems like something is wrong with the Apache or PHP configuration on the remote server. Any hints?

**Edit:**

As for now, it looks like the Server doesn't accept (or correctly handle) requests with Content-Type: multipart/form-data
(CURL uses that type when setting an array as the postfields, but not when setting a string.)

Since I need to send a file with the request, i have to use the multipart/form-data. So how do I get the server to correctly handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` then the form is submitted as `multipart/form-data` There could be a possibility your remote end is not accepting this encoding type.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS [...]This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value` as you can see at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Thats not the problem as I tested it with   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data'));

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do `POST` request is to format postFields like this.

`VARIABLE = VALUE` separated by `&`.

**TIP:**

```
$postFields = 'var1=cons1&var2=cons2&var3=cons3&var4=cons4&var5=cons5';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://91.250.77.10/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($error) 
    echo $error;
else
    echo $contents;
```

Would be Pleased to do any more help.

Comment: How's about file upload?

Comment: @ThomasLeu ... shouldn't be a problem. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Array('file' => $filename));` or the same `var=val` that I describe above.If you want more detailed I can add into answer.

Comment: You mean I can send a file with Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'? If so, please tell me how.

Comment: @ThomasLeu .... Yes, you're right.Think about some File hosting site API taking Uploads as `POST`. Just in post Fields put the `$filename` = `PATH` to the file and it will be sent through POST request for uploading purpose.Hope, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the HTTP header contains "Expect:100-continue" field. Some Servers do not deal with this field and just wait.
You can try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect: '));
```

For more information, pls see:
[curl http 100 continue and multipartform-data post](http://www.iandennismiller.com/posts/curl-http1-1-100-continue-and-multipartform-data-post.html)